# Overloaded constructor not initializing in another page

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm working on a project to develop a UWP app.

I'm getting the above mentioned error when I click a button intended to navigate to another frame.

Here's the code of the first frame:

```
private void Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Submit();
    }
    void Submit()
    {
            DateTime? pickupdate;
            pickupdate = PickupDate.Date.DateTime;
            DateTime? retdate;
            retdate = ReturnDate.Date.DateTime;

            Reservation res = new Reservation(pickupdate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), retdate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(Reservation));
    }
```

And the code for the second frame:

```
public Reservation(string pickup, string _return)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PickupDateDisplay.Text = pickup;
        ReturnDateDisplay.Text = _return;
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Ok so I overloaded the Reservation() constructor and now the code for the second frame looks like this:

```
    public Reservation()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Reservation(string pickupdate,string retdate)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PickupDateDisplay.Text = pickupdate;
        ReturnDateDisplay.Text = retdate;
    }
```

Now I don't get any errors on runtime but the PickupDateDisplay.Text and ReturnDateDisplay.Text does not change

Comment: Read the answer, do what it says, if you can't fix, come back [edit] and add details with what you found, what you tried, and what happened.

Comment: This is happening because when navigating using `Frame.Navigate` method the method is using parameter less constructor of the given page. To pass parameters to page when navigating, use [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8cb42356-82bc-4d77-9bbc-ae186990cfd5/passing-parameters-during-navigation-in-windows-8?forum=winappswithcsharp)...

Comment: I'm working on UWP for Windows 10. The solution you suggested is for Windows 8 apps. @MarianDolinský

Comment: I know, but it works the same in UWP

Comment: Then how do I put OnNavigatedTo event? @MarianDolinský

Comment: I've updated the question @renévogt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the `Frame.Navigate` method that is used for navigation uses parameter less constructor of the given page. To pass parameters to the target page you should use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Frame_Navigate_Windows_UI_Xaml_Interop_TypeName_System_Object_) overload of the method.

```
void Submit()
{
    DateTime? pickupdate = PickupDate.Date.DateTime;
    DateTime? retdate    = ReturnDate.Date.DateTime;

    // This is useless, this instance is not used anywhere (Frame.Navigate creates its own new instance)
    // Reservation res = new Reservation(pickupdate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), retdate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));

    string[] parameters = { pickupdate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), retdate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") };
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Reservation), parameters);
}
```

**Reservation page:**

```
string[] parameters;

public Reservation()
{
    Loaded += (sender, e) =>
    {
        PickupDateDisplay.Text = parameters[0];
        ReturnDateDisplay.Text = parameters[1];
    }

    InitializeComponent();
}

// This ctor is useless too
// public Reservation(string pickupdate,string retdate)
// {
//    InitializeComponent();
//    PickupDateDisplay.Text = pickupdate;
//    ReturnDateDisplay.Text = retdate;
// }

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    parameters = (string[])e.Parameter;
}
```